# 12Factor app codebase factor should I split

Tags: node.js, heroku, 12factor

I have been recently quite seduced by the 12Factor app as it is strong guidelines I should force myself to follow. 
So on a project I'm working on currently I have decided to use them.
Though I am having a doubt about my code structure:

I have a website that will just create new jobs and people can consult the results of the jobs there. The jobs are queued into a distributed queue (ftm Redis) and workers take each job and execute them. 
I decided to split the codebase in 2:

- the actual site which will queue jobs and users will access the result.
- the workers that are totally autonomous.

There is a node package in the middle which encapsulate the communication (queueing etc) and the only communication between nodes is through Redis.

So I just wanted to be sure that this was still coherent with 12factor as I am building a distributed system.
If not should I build everything in one codebase with a launch script which either launch one or the other?

Thx for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep it simple, but no simpler then makes sense. If it is simpler for you to keep it all in one codebase start out that way. Development is an iterative process, assume you are doing it wrong and be prepared to change things when they start to get unwieldy.

Premature optimization (or abstraction) of your code (or workflow) is always unwise.

Comment: This is true. However, making it in a single code base would make it rely on dependencies that don't really exist (I'm thinking about express for example). But it's true that one code base will make things easier including deployment.

Comment: I think I would start out with one and when you find that you can maintain them as a system of apps instead of an app split it apart. We do this at heroku fairly often. We will start writing something then notice that there is unnecessary coupling between components of the app and split them up into a system of apps when we refactor them.

Answer (score 1):

> I decided to split the codebase in 2

Well, the first item on the 12 factors website says "One codebase tracked in revision control, many deploys"

From your description, I don't think it's possible to tell how well you followed the guidelines.

Comment: If both could be used as independent pieces of software and could be maintained as such it might make sense to keep them apart.

Comment: Yes what made me hesitate is: "If there are multiple codebases, it’s not an app – it’s a distributed system. Each component in a distributed system is an app, and each can individually comply with twelve-factor."

Comment: Yes, it's a trade-off, there is no right answer. Make a list of features you are likely to add next. How many would require touching both codebases? If it's most of them, then think about joining them back into 1 repo.